# multiple pages in a frame? don't get updated. what am i missing?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

So here is the scenario. I have 3 `xaml`:

- MainWindow
- Page1
- Page2

Under MainWindow I have a button named "Page1" and a frame named "Frame1"

Code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.
  Dim page1 As New Page1
  Frame1.Navigate(page1)
End Sub
```

So it would display the `Page1.xaml` to "Frame1"

Then under `Page1.xaml`, I have another button named "Page2"

Code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Dim p2 As New page2
  Dim main As New MainWindow

  main.Frame1.Navigate(p2)
End Sub
```

The frame will not cause any changes upon clicking the button inside "Page1" that is inside "Frame1" and inside "MainWindow"

I think i'm missing something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, your problem appears to be that you are instantiating a new main window in your button 1 click event, rather than referencing the existing main window. So while you are actually calling the Frame1 Navigate method, you're actually doing it on a completely different window that just so happens to be invisible.

What you need to do is find a reference to Page1's parent MainWindow. This can be accomplished several ways.

- You could use a routed event and raise it from Page1 and handle it on
  your MainWindow.
- You create a public property on Page1 and pass it your MainWindow instance when Page1 is created.
- You could also crawl up the visual tree, starting at Page1, until you find MainWindow and then do your navigation. I'll demonstrate that in the code below.

**XAML For Page 1**

```
<Page x:Class="WpfApplication1.Page1"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
    Title="Page1">

    <Grid>
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                Click="Page2Button_Click"
                Content="Page 2" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**Code-Behind for Page 1**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Page1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Page1
    {
        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Page2Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var mainWindow = GetParentWindow(this);
            if (mainWindow != null) mainWindow.Frame1.Navigate(new Page2());
        }

        private static MainWindow GetParentWindow(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            while (obj != null)
            {
                var mainWindow = obj as MainWindow;
                if (mainWindow != null) return mainWindow;
                obj = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(obj);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! that worked! Thank u very much.. last request please.. CAn u explain to me what happened there? for me to understand more. thanks a lot man.

Comment: Sure. Which part would you like clarification on? Your original problem or the solution?

Comment: oops sorry did'nt read all on the top due to excitement. thank you again SO MUCH! :)

Comment: Sir brandon. i have another question. i just can't get it how to use Directcast or trycast. hmm. in my page1 i have a button and text box, page 2 label. what i write on my text box it must display it on page2 label? sorry. :(